# Grouping PHP objects to create "unique" lines in HTML table

Tags: php

Let's say I have a database of cars that are available for dealerships to buy in bulk. They fill out a form on our site and I send them a purchase order for them to sign.

In that purchase order, I have a table outlining the cars that will be delivered should they sign the contract.

I am having a hard time trying to group the cars without making multiple queries to the database.
Here is a simple layout of the table

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Transmission</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price per Vehicle</th>
            <th>Total Cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to be able to make 1 pull from the database (since it is large) and produce a table body as follows

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Nissan</td>
        <td>Altima</td>
        <td>CVT</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>20000</td>
        <td>40000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nissan</td>
        <td>Maxima</td>
        <td>Automatic</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>30000</td>
        <td>90000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nissan</td>
        <td>GTR</td>
        <td>Automatic</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>130000</td>
        <td>130000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nissan</td>
        <td>GTR</td>
        <td>Manual</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>130000</td>
        <td>260000</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The data comes from my table as 8 separate objects. I am trying to write a script that ingests the response
and returns an array (which can be easily transformed into a table) that GROUPS the objects by three key attributes.

"make, model, and transmission"

Any object that matches another object in the response on all three of the above attributes should represent one new line in the table with the quantity column matching accordingly.

My approach original approach was to keep querying the database...but that was too wasteful.
I was able to figure out how to match on one attribute

```
$noRepeatMake = [];
$i = 1;
foreach($cars as $car){
    if(!in_array($car->make, $noRepeatMake)) {
        $count .= Cars::where('BAID', $id)->where('make', $car->make)->where('model', $car->model)->where('trans', $car->trans)->count();
        if ($i < $cars->count()) {
            $count .= ",";
        }  
        array_push($noRepeatMake, $car->make);
    }
    $i++;
}
$roomCount = explode(",", $roomCount);
```

Comment: You should solve this in the query. If this is an SQL database, you should be able to produce the elements of your table in a query that uses `group by`.

Comment: @trincot yup... that did the trick!

Comment: OK, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should solve this in the query.

If this is an SQL database, you should be able to produce the elements of your table in a query that uses `group by` (on the three fields you mentioned). You can then apply aggregation on the other, numerical field(s) (`sum`, `min`, `max`,... as you need).

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue when dealing with object.
I think in your case, you can create a key from group of 3 key attributes:

**Ex: $key = md5(make + model + transmission)**

So any object got the same md5 hash, will be store in same array

> $array[ md5(make + model + transmission) ]

Hope this help

Comment: a lot smarter than my approach haha. I should try this